# Is there a Heroku webhook when a Heroku Add-On is attached (not created)?

Tags: heroku

Can Heroku notify Add-on creators when an existing Add-on is attached (not created)?

Heroku Add-ons can be shared between multiple apps ([Heroku Docs: making your Add-on shareable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/making-your-add-on-shareable)), and there's this [Add-on Partner API reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-on-partner-api-reference), but I found no information about receiving webhooks/information when an existing Add-on is attached to a second app.

I thought about using the API for periodically checking the attached apps (which is possible). But if I wanted to give different config variables to each attached app, while sharing the same Add-on (and billing, which I assume is the reason behind this feature), using the readonly API doesn't help.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as an add-on provider, you can subscribe to an `api:addon-attachment` Webhook topic that would be triggered whenever your add-on attachment is being created / destroyed.

You can read more about using Webhooks as an add-on partner, [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/addon-webhooks).